# option+left and option+right skip special characters

Tags: terminal, keyboard, iterm, keybindings

So I have a new Mac M1

I'm trying to set up the terminal as it was in my previous system.

The problem now is that when using option+arrow (left or right) it jumps to the next space character instead of the next special character.

I have set the keybindings to the "natural text editing" preset in iterm2.

In summary. This happens:

```
 /example/path/here       option->         /example/path/here
^                                                            ^
cursor                                                       cursor
```

What I want

```
 /example/path/here       option->         /example/path/here
^                                                  ^
cursor                                             cursor
```

Answer (score 2):

So essentially my problem was with zsh. The default word separation behaviour is different there.

To fix it I just had to include this in my `~/.zshrc` file:

```
# Bash-like navigation
autoload -U select-word-style
select-word-style bash
```

Comment: After reading a dozen questions, this helped me. Natural text editing was properly set and worked for me in the past, but this time i was struggling with navigating word by word in paths. thank you!